# Magento Product image upload (Flash) not working

Tags: magento-1.9, patches, supee-8788

After apply patch in magento product image upload (flash) not working it will display message image uploaded but it's not listed in images table.

Please see this image.

[image]

Help me.!

Thank you.

Comment: can you check once : https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/140963/image-upload-issue-after-patch-8788-install-on-1-9-2-4

Comment: Yes, I have try that but still not work.!

Comment: can you check this one too : https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/140550/security-patch-supee-8788-possible-problems

Comment: Yes, i have manually change that files whenever i have removed the "skin/adminhtml/default/default/media/flex.swf, skin/adminhtml/default/default/media/uploader.swf and skin/adminhtml/default/default/media/uploaderSingle.swf" then the buttons (browse and upload) are not display in admin.!

Answer (score 2):

Here are few solution you can try:

1. Clean/flush all cache manually
2. Try in different browser as this issue can be from flash
3. Clear browser cache and restart it.

Comment: I have already flush cache manually and also check in both mozila firefox and google chrome web browsers seems not any changes.
I also used this "No-Flash-Image-Uploader-master" extenstion but still not work for me
Thanks for reply.