# How to upload new product images after Adobe Flash Player EOL?

Tags: magento-1.7, file-upload

I am wondering how can I upload new product images to my Magento 1 store?
Adobe has blocked all Flash content today and I can't see upload button now.

However, I am already working on my new Magento 2 store and it's gonna take few more months meanwhile it's really important for me to upload new images.

I really appreciate any help. Thanks heaps.

Comment: The flash uploader for Magento 1 was removed in a 1.9 release many years ago...

Comment: I am currently using Magento 1.7

Answer (score 0):

Magento has released a patch with the name SUPEE-8788 for this and some other problems.
Look at [this blog post](https://www.myeasypconline.com/fixing-magento-1-x-image-upload/#:%7E:text=To%20removed%20the%20Flash%20player,upload%20SUPEE%2D8788%20using%20FTP.&text=You%20can%20also%20download%20SUPEE,%2C%201.8%2C%201.9%20versions%20here.&text=FTP%20upload%20the%20files%2C%20overwriting,and%20delete%20the%20below%20files)

Answer (score 0):

If after applying the patch the "new non flash" upload buttons don't work, [check here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/140963/image-upload-issue-after-patch-8788-install-on-1-9-2-4)